# Send component value and another parameter to a listener

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, primefaces, listener

I have a panel grid with various checkboxes. A checkbox is associated with a certain mask. When the checkbox is pressed, the value of the checkbox(checked/unckecked) and a mask parameter specific to that checkbox should be passed to a listener.

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{options.mustChangePasswordMask}">
    <p:ajax listener="#{options.selectionChanged}" /> 
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>

<p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{options.mustChangePasswordMask}">
    <p:ajax listener="#{options.selectionChanged('MASK_1')}" /> 
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

Both these code fragments do only half of the job that I want. I want to use the listener in all the checkboxes so I can't use the mustChangePasswordMask property inside the listener. Is it possible to send the checkbox value as a parameter to the listener or in another way accessible to the listener?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The current component is in EL available as implicit variable `#{component}`. In input component this will be set with an instance of [`UIInput`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html) class which in turn has a [`getValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIOutput.html#getValue%28%29) method which returns the submitted, converted and validated value. So, this should do

```html
<p:ajax listener="#{options.selectionChanged(component.value)}" />
```

Comment: I want to use the same listener in all the checkboxes. I will update the question with this information.

Comment: @BalusC can both the `event` and aditional parameters be provided? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39143601/ I have a question on the subject