# Add additional parameter to JSF Ajax event listener

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, parameters

I am having an Ajax listener who should redirect to item view page. However since I am using generic type as model I would like to specify additionally in my common data table controller what is the view with a second parameter.

Unfortunately one can choose between two listener approaches one using **event** parameter which helps identifying the object and the second one gives you the opportunity to send **free param** but lacks the event.

**template**:

```html
<p:dataTable value="#{aObj.objList}" var="item" ... selectionMode="single">
              
  <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{aObj.viewItem}" />
  <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{aObj.viewItem('myItemView?_id=')}" />

  ...
</p:dataTable>
```

**controller**:

```java
public void viewItem(SelectEvent event) {
  // ...
}
    
public void viewItem(String viewUrl) {
  // ...
}
```

I can add additional properties to the bean but since it is generic and providing model items doesn't feel right to pollute it.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: Relevant thread: https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=37824 
It worked for me with  p:inputtext+f:param+p:ajax.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You could set an attribute in your data table and read it in your select listener. To do so, use `<f:attribute name="..." value="..."/>`. From the [documentation](https://javaserverfaces-spec-public.java.net/nonav/snapshots/jsf-spec-2.2-SNAPSHOT-20110616/JSF_20110616.pdf):

> #### Constraints
>
> Must be nested inside a `UIComponent` custom action.
>
> #### Description
>
> Locate the closest parent `UIComponent` custom action instance (...). If the associated component already has a component
>   attribute with that name, take no action. Otherwise, call the `isLiteralText()` method on the argument `value`. If it
>   returns `true`, store the value in the component’s attribute Map under the name derived above. If it returns `false`, store
>   the `ValueExpression` in the component’s `ValueExpression` Map under the name derived above.

So, taking the attribute you tried to set in your comment, you should use it like:

XHTML:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{aObj.objList}" var="item" .... selectionMode="single">

  <f:attribute name="test" value="abc" />
  <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{aObj.viewItem}" />

  ...
</p:dataTable>
```

Listener:

```
public void viewItem(SelectEvent event) {
  String test = (String) event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("test");
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

When you want to add request parameters, which are specific to the `ajax` tag, you can do at the `onstart` method:

```html
<p:ajax onstart="cfg.ext.params.push({name: 'name', value: 'value'});"/>
```

Usually, you should solve parameters using the model.

Comment: oh? Never new this. What PF version(s) does this work on?

Comment: This is working at least from 5.0, maybe you have to add cfg.ext = {params: []}

Comment: For me it is working with Primefaces 10 like this:

cfg.ext={params:[{name:'request_parameter_name', value:'request_parameter_value'}]};