# jsf valueChangeListener working intermittently in PrimeFaces treeTable

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

I've built a PrimeFaces treeTable to contain (at top level) details for a product that people have ordered. The second level shows the individual members who have ordered that product.

I've used the rendered attribute to hide some columns for the second level so it ends up looking like this (member names retracted).

[image: treeTable showing products and the people who have ordered]

I've put a valueChangeListener on the h:inputText control in the 'Allocation' column. The code in the valueChangeListener method gets called, it works out which row to update in the orders database and then updates that row with the allocation value that the user entered. It works, so I don't have a problem with what the listener method code is doing.

Here's the problem... When I expand a product row I may have several rows with an allocation input box. The valueChangeListener only ever gets called on the first row I update. In the picture above, I entered 103 first then 101 and 102. For the second product I entered 202 then 201. Only 103 and 202 were saved in the database. I've tested the pattern and it seems to be the case that the valueChangeListener only gets called for the first allocation that gets updated for a particular product. I can go on to expand another product row and, as before, I get one chance at updating the allocations for the second product.

I know whether the valueChangeListener method is being called because I write a Log record to my database as soon as the method is entered, before any other code is called. In the above example I have log records for the allocations 103 and 202.

#### [Update]

If I enter the allocation for one row, then contract and expand the product, then enter the allocation for another row, etc, then it works. I can't expect the users to do that of course; I'm just mentioning it because it might provide a clue as to what could be going wrong.

This is how the Allocation column is defined within the treeTable:

```xhtml
<p:column headerText="Supplier Qty" style="background-color:#{vAllocationRecord.rowtype=='Product' ? '#fafafa' : (vAllocationRecord.rowtype=='OrderLine' ? '#fff' : '')};text-align:left;">
    <h:inputText id="supplierqty_input" value="#{vAllocationRecord.supplierqty}"
                 rendered="#{(vAllocationRecord.rowtype eq 'Product') and (loginBean.hasRole('Ordering'))}"
                 size="7" valueChangeListener="#{orderFormBean.handleSupplierQtyChange}"
                 disabled="#{vAllocationRecord.supplier eq 'Stock'}">
        <p:ajax />
        <f:converter converterId="bigDecimalPlainDisplay" />
    </h:inputText>
    <p:keyFilter for="supplierqty_input" mask="pnum" />     
    <h:outputText id="supplierqty_output" value="#{vAllocationRecord.supplierqty}"
                  rendered="#{!(loginBean.hasRole('Ordering'))}" >
        <f:converter converterId="bigDecimalPlainDisplay" />
    </h:outputText>
</p:column>
```

Comment: can you please create a [mcve].

Comment: What happens if you move the valueChangeListener down as a listener on the p:ajax and transfer the record as the answer here ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39143601/send-additional-parameter-to-ajax-event-listener . I would also use p:inputText if you can

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I used p:inputText, also in conjunction with moving the listener to the ajax tag. It still only calls the listener once for each expanded product.