# Pass additional parameters to the LazyDataModel load method on pagination

Tags: ajax, primefaces, datagrid, paginator

I want to pass additional parameters when a paginator button is clicked. The data looks like this:

```html
<p:dataGrid 
    var="citem" 
      value="#{group.lazyItemGroup}"
      paginator="true" 
      rows="4"
      lazy="true"
        columns="2"
        layout="grid"
        id="items"
        paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
        rowsPerPageTemplate="6,12,16"
>
    ...
    ...
    ...
</p:dataGrid>
```

Can I use something like this?

```html
<p:inputText id="id" value="#{group.id}" type="hidden" />
or
<f:attribute name="id" value="#{group.id}" />
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send additional parameter to Ajax event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39143601/send-additional-parameter-to-ajax-event-listener)

Comment: I do not use a p:dataTable. I use a p:dataGrid. I do not have to add an action listener to row selected. I have to pass additional parameters when a page number button(or next page button) will be pressed.

Comment: If you cannot be more precise in which sort of parameter, differences for the buttons, etc, otherwise the duplicate **is** a duplicate...

Comment: I do not have to click a row. I have to click a next page button. A user clicks a next page button and load() function is called(I use lazy="true"), but I need to send some data to a managed bean before load is called. I have attached a picture. Please look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to the `load` method of the `LazyDataModel` you have implemented, then no, you cannot simply add parameters to that method.

Since you were talking about "when a paginator button is clicked", I assumed you had a `page` event listener in place. Apparently you haven't, so add that to your `p:dataGrid`:

```
<p:dataGrid ...>
  <p:ajax event="page"
          listener="#{yourBean.yourListener}"/>
</p:dataGrid>
```

And to your bean:

```
public void yourListener(PageEvent event) {
  ...
}
```

In your listener you can pass anything to your custom lazy data model instance, and pick that up in the `load` method. You could also add a `<f:attribute .../>` to your data grid component, which can be read in the listener method (see [Send additional parameter to Ajax event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39143601/send-additional-parameter-to-ajax-event-listener)).

Please note that you can get the page from the page event:

```
event.getPage();
```

This might help in determining what additional data to set.

Comment: You cannot add parameters to that method, but you can set them in a bean which you use inside the load method. I do it all the time for passing a 'multi-tenant' field that needs to be used in the queries in the load method. Works great.

Comment: @Kukeltje Sure thing. We are doing the same thing more or less, when constructing the lazy model we provide a base query builder. I never had the need to change anything on pagination though.

Comment: I have used event="page" and f:attribute. It is works. I have got some parameters in my listener method. Thanks a lot.