# How to call listener in a p:selectCheckboxMenu with item passed in inside listener as parameter

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectcheckboxmenu

I am using the selectCheckboxMenu to enable multiple users be selected. What I am trying to achieve is that, every time the user does a selection, the event will call the listener and pass in the selection as a parameter. Something like this

```
<p:selectCheckboxMenu id="user" value="#{userBean.selectedUserList}" 
   multiple="true" filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains">
     <f:selectItems value="#{userBean.users}" var="selectedUser"
        itemValue="#{selectedUser}"/>
    <p:ajax event="change"
        listener="#{userBean.addThisUserIntoAnotherList(selectedUser)}"/>
</p:selectCheckboxMenu>
```

I have tried to add the var="selectedUser" in the selectCheckBoxMenu tag instead but both return null as the parameter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send additional parameter to Ajax event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39143601/send-additional-parameter-to-ajax-event-listener)

Comment: Doesn't the `<p:selectCheckboxMenu valueChangeListener=...` attribute help?

Comment: Still returns null @JasperdeVries

Comment: listeners work, but sending individual selection into the listener doesn't @Selaron

Comment: Using the `valueChangeListener`, you get a `javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent` which holds `new` and `old` component `value`. This way you can determine which element was selected on the current event.

Comment: The better duplicate would be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879138/when-to-use-valuechangelistener-or-fajax-listener