# PrimeFaces ajax does not pass param value to backing bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am working on drag and drop functionality. I need to move content of column in `<p:dataTable>` to another column, but different row. (this works) The problem is, that I need to pass values from the column to my backing bean (and process data), which doesn't work. Data do not pass to backing bean and network tab in browser sends request without value. So I assume it is a problem in xhtml part.

PrimeFaces version: 12.0.0 (also tried 11...)
Java: 17

I am trying to assign string `passingValue` in `myController`.

```html
<h:form id="myForm">
    <p:dataTable id="table" value="#{myController.myValues}" var="oneValue">
        <p:column headerText="Column test">
            <p:draggable for="item" revert="true" axis="y"/>
            <h:panelGroup id="column1">
                <h:outputText id="item" value="value"/>
            </h:panelGroup>
            <p:droppable for="column1" tolerance="touch">
                <p:ajax listener="#{myController.myValues}" process="@this">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{myController.passingValue}" value="foo_string"/>
                    <f:param name="param" value="another_foo_string"/>
                </p:ajax>
            </p:droppable>
        </p:column>
    </:p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

myController.java:

```java
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class MyController implements Serializable {

    private String passingValue;
    /*
        getter and setter
    */

    public void handleDrop(DragDropEvent event) {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        String param = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("param");
    
        logger.info("handleDrop triggered");
        logger.info(event);
        logger.info(param);
        logger.info(passingValue);
    
    }
}
```

I tried both methods (`f:setPropertyActionListener` and `f:param`) separately I also tried `<ui:param>` and `<p:draggable data="{'name': 'value'}"` and `event.getData()` with no luck.

Current output is:

```
handleDrop triggered
*event stuff* //exists
null
null
```

nulls should be `foo_string` and `another_foo_string`

I need somehow pass the `oneValue` (dataTable iteration) to my java handling function, both of them (old position of dragged object and as well as new one)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add additional parameter to JSF Ajax event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39143601/add-additional-parameter-to-jsf-ajax-event-listener)

Comment: Thank you, I tried it, but id didn't work in my example, because I had it enclosed in ajax. See answer. But thank you for it, because I got the idea to put it out of ajax after reading your example.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had the `f:param` and `f:attribute` enclosed by `p:ajax`. (`f:setPropertyActionListener` didn't work anyway...)

This works:

```
<p:droppable for="column1" tolerance="touch">
    <f:param name="param" value="foo_string"/>
    <f:attribute name="param2" value="another_foo_string"/>
    <p:ajax listener="#{myController.handler}" process="@this" />
</p:droppable>
```

myController.java:

```
public void handleDrop(DragDropEvent event) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    String value = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("param");
    logger.info("Passed value: " + value);
    String value2 = (String) event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("param2");
    logger.info("Passed value 2: " + value2);
}
```

output:

```
Passed value: another_foo_string
Passed value 2: another_another_foo_string
```