# send attributes in ajax event (JSF - calendar)

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I've this code in the view JSF

```
<p:calendar class="fechaCalendar-#{producto.value.codigo}-0" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" mindate="#{pedidoInicialesMB.minDate}" maxdate="#{pedidoInicialesMB.maxDate}" value="#{pedidoInicialesMB.pedido.fecha}">
<p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{pedidoInicialesMB.actualizarFecha}" execute="@this" render="@none">
<f:attribute name="codigo" value="#{producto.value.codigo}" />
<f:attribute name="fechaEntrega" value="#{fechaEntrega}" />
</p:ajax>
</p:calendar>
```

And this is the method:

```
public void actualizarFecha(SelectEvent event) {
    Date nuevaFecha = (Date) event.getObject();
        
        
    String codigo = (String) event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("codigo");
        
    String fechaEntrega = (String) event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("fechaEntrega");
}
```

nuevaFecha have value, but codigo and fechaEntrega not.

How I can get the values?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add additional parameter to JSF Ajax event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39143601/add-additional-parameter-to-jsf-ajax-event-listener)

Comment: Please note that p:calendar is deprecated. Use p:datePicker instead.